# React - Expand and collapse every child of parent and child of child element in Recursive component using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tree

App.js file

```
function App() {
  const [expandAll, setExpandAll] =useState(false)
  const [name, setName]=useState("")
  const [data, setData] = useState(manipulateData(originalData));
  const handleExpand = (title) => {
    setExpandAll(!expandAll)
    setName(title)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.title} style={{display:"flex",justifyContent:"space-between"}}>
        <MainAccordion item={item} expandAll={expandAll} name={name}/>
        <div style={{padding:"2px"}} onClick={()=>handleExpand(item.title)}>Expand</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

MainAccordion.js file

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function MainAccordion({ item, expandAll }) {
  let [collapse, setCollapse] = useState(false);
  const [child, setChild] = useState([]);
//   console.log(expandAll,collapse)

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCollapse(!collapse);
  };

  const getData = (item) => {
    // console.log(item);
    const arr = Array.from(item.children, function (entry) {
      return { key: entry[0], value: entry[1] };
    });
    setChild(arr);
  };

  const handleExpand = () => {
    setCollapse(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (item.children){
        getData(item);
    } 
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ paddingLeft: 10, cursor: "pointer" }}>
      <div onClick={handleClick}>{item.title}</div>
      {collapse
        ? item.children &&
          child.map((item) => {
            // console.log(item)
            return (
              <div key={item.key} style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}>
                <MainAccordion  item={item.value} expandAll={expandAll} />
              </div>
            );
          })
        : ""}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainAccordion;
```

If I click on the name of parent, expand and collapse works and shows the child element, clicking on child element shows more child elements but I want to open all the child elements of that parent when I click on the expand text.
Not able to figure out the functionality.

Comment: I think initializing collapse state of MainAccordion with !expandAll will solve the problem. 
const [collapse, setCollapse = useState(!expandAll)

Comment: And I don't think ternary operator in return part is not correct. Collapse means accordion is not open, so I think we should show nothing when collapse is true and return children when false.